# Кроссовок, ботинок, тапок

Tags: словоизменение

Какая из форм следующих названий обуви в ед. числе возможна, кроме нормативного употребления в форме женского рода?

Тапок, кроссовок, ботинок?

Comment: Тапок, кроссовок, ботинок - люди так и говорят. Никогда не слышал эти слова в ж.р.

Comment: @oleedd Отнюдь. Люди говорят по-разному.

Comment: Не слышал ни по ТВ, ни в интернете, ни вокруг. И даже и не догадывался, что так можно сказать. Может, где-то там, кто знает где так и говорят. Думаю, что эти люди в меньшинстве.

Comment: @tum_ Как ответила gramota.ru: "Словарная фиксация всегда несколько отстает от жизни языка. С этим приходится мириться."

Comment: @oleedd "Не слышал ни по ТВ, ни в интернете, ни вокруг." - А это ни о чем не говорит, тем более что ни возраста, ни региона вы не указываете.  Просто люди очень редко разговаривают о тапках в единственном числе. Я вот с точностью до наоборот, не слышал вариант "тапок", пока не поселился в универской общаге, где были люди со всего Союза. Поначалу это очень смешило, потом привык. Сейчас сам говорю и так, и сяк, в зависимости от собеседника... И с "меньшинством" вы тоже торопитесь с выводами. Но где взять такую статистику - я не знаю.

Comment: **ботинок** в форме женского рода?!

Comment: @Владимир: Кстати, да. Заголовок вопроса у вас с содержанием плохо стыкуется...

Comment: Почему плохо? Как следовало бы назвать?

Comment: Да уже неважно. Тут, кажется, что-то произошло, а я всё пропустил... **Ботинок** не имеет *нормативного употребления в форме женского рода*, поэтому вопрос звучит странно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С ботинком вариантов нет(**`*`**), а вот с тапками и кроссовками всё сложнее.

Словари дают женский род, очень немногие добавляют *разг.* тапок. Т.е. литературная норма - **тапка, кроссовка**.

Тем не менее, миллионы русских говорят (один) **тапок** и (один) **кроссовок**, и *ощущают* данный предмет в мужском роде и никак иначе. По моим наблюдениям, это более всего характерно для жителей южных областей России - Воронежская, Брянская и т.д.

**Добавлено**:

**`*`** - оказалось, что и с ботинками тоже не всё так просто:

[Этимологический словарь русского языка Семёнова](http://endic.ru/semenov/Botinki-487.html)

> **Ботинки**
>
> ботинки
>
> Французское – bottine.
>
> Слово «ботинки» появилось в
>   русском языке с середины XIX в. В словарях – с 1847 г., сначала –
>   **только в форме ж.р.**: ботинка – «женский полусапожок», а также «гамаши,
>   штиблеты». Позже ботинки стало означать не только «женские, детские
>   сапожки», но и «род обуви, носимый всеми, башмаки».
>
> Слово заимствовано
>   из французского языка, где bottine («ботинок») известно с 1367 г. и
>   восходит к botte («сапог»). Родственными являются: Украинское –
>   ботинок. Польское – bucik (ботинок). Производное: боты.
>
> Этимологический словарь русского языка. М.: Русский язык от А до Я.
>   Издательство <ЮНВЕС> Москва 2003

Во французском *la bottine* - ж.р., поэтому логично, что свежезаимствованное слово первоначально тоже было женского рода.

["Толковый словарь Ушакова"](http://endic.ru/ushakov/Botinki-3157.html) также утверждает:

> **Ботинки**
>
> ботинок, ед. ботинок, ботинка, м., **и (реже) ботинка, ботинки,
>   ж.** Род обуви - невысокие сапоги без голенища, башмаки.

**Добавлено #2**

[Про "тапок"](https://touch.otvet.mail.ru/question/189090965), на мой взгляд, хорошо сформулировано:

> Слово ТАПКА испытывает колебания в роде на протяжении нескольких
>   последних десятилетий, и в наши дни всё чаще оно употребляется как
>   существительное МУЖСКОГО рода – ТАПОК. Эти колебания в роде уже
>   зафиксировали словари, указав наличие двух вариантов: ТАПКА (женский
>   род) и ТАПОК (мужской род)
>   – [http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=тапки](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8)
>
> ТАКИМ ОБРАЗОМ, ИЗМЕНИЛИ РОД: ★ с мужского на женский слова ТУФЛЯ,
>   ВУАЛЬ; ★ с женского на мужской слова ЛЕБЕДЬ, ФИЛЬМ, БОТИНОК.
>
> Процесс
>   изменения рода слова ТАПКА с женского на мужской происходит сейчас,
>   сколько он продлится, неизвестно.

Comment: Я встречал в словарях и "ботинка", и "ботинок". А вот "кроссовок" даже с пометой не встречал.

Comment: @Владимир Про "ботинку" не поверю, пока не увижу. "Кроссовок" в словаре я тоже не видел, поэтому написал *разг.* тапок. А вот слышать - слышал, и достаточно часто. Гугл-запрос "тапка или тапок" выдает [такие, например,](http://gramota.ru/forum/spravka/124890/) обсуждения. Про кроссовки аналогичным образом поищите, тоже есть.

Comment: В Петербурге никогда не говорили "тапка" и "кроссовок", (тапок, кроссовка) - это к теоретикам и составителям словарей современного языка вопрос, где они это "фиксируют" и зачем навязывают.

Comment: @Alex_ander Литературная норма, как известно, сформировалась, в основном, на базе московского диалекта, так сложилось исторически. Но тут важно понимать, что вообще такое "литературная норма". Это отдельная большая тема, но достаточно сказать, что в быту никто из нас "на ней" не говорит. Те, кто утверждают обратное, заблуждаются. Очень хорошее интервью на эту тему было с И.Левонтиной (филолог), кажется, на ПостНауке.

Comment: Например, у Ожегова: БОТИ́НКИ, -нок, ед. ч. ботинок, -нка, м. Обувь, закрывающая ногу по щиколотку.

Comment: @Владимир Это родительный падеж, надо полагать.

Comment: @Владимир Добавил в ответ о женском роде ботинок.

Comment: БОТИНКА
жен. ботинки мн., франц. полусапожки, особенно женские, сапожки с короткими, поротыми голенищами, на завязках, застежках. Толковый словарь Даля.

Answer (score 0):

Из трёх слов только два есть в словарях.

Ботинок - в словаре Кузнецова.

Тапок - в словаре Кузнецова.

(**без** пометок *разг.*)

Данный толковый словарь, возможно, новейший из всех - 2010 года.

Comment: Дополнил свой ответ ещё одним мнением про "тапок". (А что с *ботинком*, не понял? Он разве не во всех словарях есть?)

Comment: Само слово только у Кузнецова. А в других просто ед. форма при слове "ботинки".

Answer (score 0):

> кроме нормативного употребления в форме женского рода?

Ботинок нормативно - мужского. Женский род тут в страшном сне не приснится. Это первое.
Второе. Кроссовка и тапка - женского. Нормативно.

В отношении форм "кроссовок" и "тапок" (им. ед.).
Первое - очевидное просторечие, второе некоторые словари дают как разговорное, а кузнецов и вовсе признает равноправным вариантом (хотя тут он явно не в свои сани садится, его словарь - толколый, а не орфоэпический).

Это тот случай, когда "язык делают неграмотные люди". Приходится считаться. Но очень надеюсь, что дальше разговорной формы все-таки не пойдет.

(+)
Увидел упоминание ж.р. "ботинка" у Даля. Оно-то так, но мы говорим о современном языке, заимствования на момент "обкатывания" языком часто испытывают колебания в роде. Но это совершенно другая тема.

Другое дело, что можно подметить тенденцию. Для п**а**рных названий (обуви в т. ч.) мужской род чаще вытесняет женский, чем наоборот. Из обратных примеров про обувь могу вспомнить только туфлю и босоножку (ранее в им. ед. встречались также "туфель" и "босоножек"). С чем это связано - не берусь судить.