# Все-таки тапок или тапка?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

Из современной литературы (2006 г.)

*Узбек зачем-то поднял с пола **домашнюю тапку**, долго ее разглядывал, а потом попытался спрятать под халат, но Л. шлепнула его по руке.*

*— Не трогай! — прошептала она.*

*Г. вздохнул и выбросил **тапку**.*

*— Хотел исследовать, — пояснил он.*

**Информация для размышления**

1. Скажите пожалуйста, **все-таки тапок или тапка**??? Все говорят ***тапок*** но не факт, что так правильно.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Правильно: **тапка, тапочка**. Это существительные женского рода: одна тапка, старая тапочка.

2. **Из словаря Кузнецова** на Грамоте.ру

ТАПКИ, -пок, -пкам; мн. (ед. тапка, -и; ж.; тапок, -пка; м.). Мягкие лёгкие туфли без каблуков. Спортивные, домашние т. Больничные т. Парусиновые, кожаные т.

3. Обсуждение на форуме: [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/454590/Кроссовок-ботинок-тапок](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/454590/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA)

**Цитирование:**   *Ботинок* нормативно – мужского. Женский род тут в страшном сне не приснится. Это первое. Второе. *Кроссовка и тапка* – женского. Нормативно.

В отношении форм "*кроссовок*" и "***тапок***" (им. ед.).
Первое – очевидное просторечие, второе некоторые словари дают как **разговорное**, а Кузнецов и вовсе признает **равноправным** вариантом (хотя тут он явно не в свои сани садится, его словарь – толковый, а не орфоэпический).

Это тот случай, когда "**язык делают неграмотные люди**". Приходится считаться. Но очень надеюсь, что дальше разговорной формы все-таки не пойдет.

Другое дело, что можно **подметить тенденцию**. Для парных названий (обуви в т. ч.) мужской род чаще вытесняет женский, чем наоборот. Из обратных примеров про обувь могу вспомнить только ***туфлю*** и ***босоножку*** (ранее в им. ед. встречались также "туфель" и "босоножек"). С чем это связано – не берусь судить.

4. **А вы как говорите?**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1. Итак, надо "подметить тенденцию". Допустим, кто-то считает,что форма *тапка* нехарактерна для языка, в форма *тапок*  ему больше по душе, хотя он и в курсе нормативных норм. Можно ли считать таких людей **неграмотными?** Может быть, они чувствуют язык лучше, чем другие? Или нет?
2. А откуда вообще взялась **нормативная форма** «тапка»?

В Нацкорпусе вариант «тапка»  встречается редко, обычно «тапок».

Одна **тапка** соскользнула на пол.  [В. М. Шапко. 2010]

…у неё на одной ноге была клетчатая **тапка,** а на другой ― старая мамина босоножка  [Ирина Пивоварова (1986)]

Одна нога в тапке, вторая никак не нашарит свой **тапок.** [М. В. Куценогий. 2014]

А левой, обутой в кожаный **тапок**, проделывал медленные пассы над бритой головой. [Андрей Пермяков, 2013]

Ни носка, ни стоптанного **тапка**, ни английской булавки, ни засохшей половинки булочки. [Мариам Петросян (2009)]

3. **А как раньше говорили**?

Что-то мне не удалось найти в словарях **время появления** слова «тапки» в русском языке, да и происхождение у него не вполне ясное.

В Нацкорпусе до 1900 года  «тапки» вроде бы не встречаются, но есть 1922 год: Раздели меня не скоро, а сию же минуту, шинель и **тапки** взял наш «санитар» ― вместе с хлебом, деньгами и табаком. [Иван Савин. Плен. (Крым, 1920) // «Русские вести», 1922]

Comment: Я говорю "тапок".

Comment: Чудненько... Тогда я добавлю в вопрос что-нибудь хорошее о вас.  Впрочем, я и так собиралась это сделать.

Comment: Как и *oleedd*, никогда не слышал в женском роде. Для меня "тапка" звучит просторечно.

Comment: Родился и жил в Кемерове.

Comment: Я имела в виду, что в самой Москве много разных административных округов, так что в одном городе могут говорить по-разному.

Comment: О происхождении любопытное обсуждение было в ЖЖ (в 2007 году): https://ru-etymology.livejournal.com/677088.html

Comment: Ни разу не слышала в женском роде.

Comment: Прекрасно! Я вот тоже не слышала. Будем собирать статистику. :)

Comment: @Sharon Как я и предполагал, вопрос "завис". Думаю, что одна из причин в том, что он не вписывается в формат данного ресурса (Stack Exchange). Здесь всё-таки Q&A, а не форум для дискуссий.

Comment: Ладно, завис так завис, не удалять же его теперь.  Впрочем, я задавала вопросы и  волне конкретные, а именно: Когда была нормирована форма "тапка" (в каком году)?  Когда слово появилось в русском языке? Такие вопросы вроде бы не запрещены. А дискуссий я здесь действительно не наблюдаю, как и любых обсуждений тоже, да и ответов что-то не очень много.  В 2012 - 2014 годах на многие вопросы давалось несколько ответов, люди были очень активны. А теперь формат изменился или еще что случилось?

Comment: Да, эти вопросы вполне конкретны. Видимо, просто ответов на них нет ни у кого, кто сюда заглянул. Интернет источники мне, как, видимо, и вам, ничего не дали. Доступа к каким-то другим источникам у меня нет. Будем надеяться, что однажды найдётся кто-то, кто даст ответы.

Comment: Был проведен опрос народного мнения в лице консьержа (они у нас приезжие),  выглядело это  примерно так.  – Вот есть слово «тапки. А если один, то как вы скажете? – Один тапок.  – А можно сказать «одна тапка»? – Ну, так у нас только «колхозники» могут сказать. – А вы сами из какого «колхоза» будете? – Я из Курской области (смеется и на шутки не обижается). Медом угостил (сказка!) и еще привезти обещал. Хорошие люди живут в Курске! Грамотные люди, но не по Грамоте.ру.

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий к заданному вопросу**

В своем вопросе я  цитировала только  одного участника дискуссии на форуме (@behemothus), так как его мнение меня заинтересовало.

Другой участник (@tum_) в своем ответе обозначает **тенденцию** в изменении рода, а также говорит, что  форма «тапок» более всего **характерна** для жителей южных областей России – Воронежская, Брянская и т.д. Я же не из южных областей, но тоже говорю «тапок», а «тапка» мне «уши режет».

И вопрос этот **глубже и интереснее**, чем простое наблюдение статистики. Принято считать грамотным того, кто грамотен «по словарю».  А там сегодня грамотно так, а завтра по-другому. А почему – это  «не наш вопрос»?

Я же считаю **по-настоящему грамотным** того, кто, во-первых, умеет наблюдать и чувствовать языковые явления, а во-вторых, того, кто знает **историю  слова**:  когда оно появилось, какую форму имело сначала, с чем связано изменение. Если оно прогрессивно и вписывается в русскую языковую систему, то это **чувство языка**, но если искажает ее, то это **просторечие,** незнание и неграмотность.  Можно ли считать, что это **правильный подход,** или нет?

Вот о чем мне хотелось поговорить здесь.  Дискуссию по дополнительной ссылке я мельком просмотрела, но не уверена, что найду там ответ на свои вопросы.

Так когда же слово «тапки» вообще появилось в русском языке. а также когда  форму «тапка» стали считать нормативной?  Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Говорят, что формой ед. числа мало пользуются, но в художественной литературе это **отнюдь не редкость.**

Comment: *а также говорит, что форма «тапок» более всего характерна для жителей южных областей России – Воронежская, Брянская и т.д.* - там ещё была фраза "по моим наблюдениям". Увы, наблюдения мои ограниченны. Следовало написать: "например, слово *тапок* использовали мои знакомые из Воронежа и Брянска", со знакомыми из других регионов эта тема просто не поднималась.

Comment: Да, со статистикой во все времена было не очень просто, а сейчас особенно сложно сделать какие-то выводы.  Даже в наших обсуждениях приводятся разные мнения жителей одного региона.  Люди очень болезненно воспринимают языковые ситуации – начинаешь думать, как бы чего лишнего не сказать.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже всегда слышал тапок "он". Женский род услышал лишь у "грамотеев" внятно не могущих обосновать свою позицию и почему-то требующих произносить "она".
Самарская область.

Comment: Да, это все они, они)))  Обидно, что хорошим писателям приходится следовать их рекомендациям.  "У нас только в колхозе так могут сказать", — так мне говорили простые люди. Но глас народа до них не доходит))